# Выводится лишнее число через printf

Tags: c++, printf

```
void HA_tabfun(double a, double b, int N, int i){
    double h = fabs((a - b)/N);
    cout << "----------------" << endl;
    cout << "   x" << "    :    " << "y" << endl;
    cout << "----------------" << endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= N + 1; i++) {
        cout << "   " << printf("%.*f", 5, a) << "    :    " << HA_f(a) << endl;
        a = a + h;
    }
    cout << "----------------" << endl;

}
```

При вызове функции получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как избавиться от семерки?

Comment: ¿А зачем вы печатаете результат вызова `printf`? Собственно не надо мешать cout и printf.

Comment: Поржал от души)) Вставить принтф в cout, этож постараться надо. Главное как красиво влезло.

Comment: А зачем вообще это "смешение языков"? Или С, или С++...

Comment: @Harry вывести число с определённым количеством символов с printf гораздо проще, чем с cout.

Comment: Тогда и `HA_f(a)` надо выводить через `printf`, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Harry HA_f может и возвратить какой-то объект, с перегруженным оператором << и его уже в printf запихнуть непросто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 появляется от того, что это результат вызова printf, 7 символов напечаталось.

Можно так убрать:

```
cout << "   ";
printf("%.*f", 5, a);
cout << "    :    " << HA_f(a) << endl;
```

Comment: Тогда уж и все пробелы вместе с `:` тоже воткнуть в `printf()`